# How to automatically update IIS handler mappings when upgrading application to ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, iis

I recently migrated several applications from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.5.  The applications we a mix of ASP.NET 2 and ASP.NET 4 applications.  They all ran fine in the target IIS 7.5 environment.

One of my team members then upgraded an application from ASP.NET 2.0 to ASP.NET 4.  Application no longer works because the Handler Mappings in IIS are still configured to pass .aspx files to the ASP.NET 2 processor.  I can manually go in and start tweaking the handler mappings, but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Is there a process that I am supposed to use either on the IIS 7.5 server or as part of my application deployment that will automatically set the handler mappings to be correct for an ASP,NET v4 application?  (And, for the sake of completeness, I have the application configured to use an application pool in classic mode with .NET V4)

By the way, the applications that were already .NET V4 at the time of migration already have the correct V4 handler mappings.

Thanks.  I have been searching all day...

Comment: [`aspnet_regiis.exe -i`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125264/whats-the-difference-between-aspnet-regiis-ir-and-aspnet-regiis-iru)?

Comment: Thanks, Uwe.  I figured it out with your assistance.  I didn't use the -i option.  I believe I used the -ir instead.  The good news is that I now have the handler mappings that are required.